# "time clause problem " with when

Tags: grammaticality, past-habitual

> "What if my wife were the daughter of the head of the
>   electricity department of my district?"
>
> "She would get the threat of divorce every time [that is, *when* or *whenever*]
>   the electricity supply **is/was** cut off."

Please consider the second paragraph of
my sentences. As per the rule we should use "present
tense" after time clause, including "when". That would indicate using *is*.

But since it's a hypothetical sentence I should use "the past
tense" here, shouldn't I? That would mean using *was*.

Which verb form is correct?

Comment: Your *she **would** get* looks like a "habitual action in the past" usage, so one would expect that to be paired with a past tense "time clause". Note that ***cut off*** (often, ***cut out***) can be used intransitively in contexts such as *The electricity supply cut out again last night*, so your example is past tense regardless of whether ***was*** is present or not. Also note that *She **would cry** whenever he **shouts** at her* is not a valid utterance, because of the mixed tenses. Whether or not to include ***when*** in your example is a stylistic choice, but I wouldn't normally.

Comment: It's really not clear whether *when* is actually included in your sentence or not. It shouldn't be there. Are you just using it to help explain "every time" meaning "whenever"?

Comment: 'Every time that' (often reduced to 'every time') is used, not 'every time when' (or 'whenever', as Andrew says, is used instead).

Comment: @FumbleFingers *(If she were to appoint the manager) she would be criticised every time the team lost*. That looks to me a grammatically identical structure. But I don't see that *she would be criticised* is an "habitual action of the past". It is a normal hypothesis ensuing from an *if clause*. And such calls for the past-tense in the adverbial clause.

Comment: @Andrew Leach You are right. I just used "when " to explain "every time ".    with "whenever ", Is my sentence correct?  She would get the threat of divorce whenever the
electricity supply (was) cut off. 



Please give me a clear explanation. Is there any problem with using "Past Tense"?

Comment: @WS2: The text has been reformatted so it's clearer now, but somehow when I first looked at this, I didn't register OP's "background supposition" before the example sentence. But as he says, it's a hypothetical scenario (not *here, now, present*), so we still use the "past tense". Though for this *specific* context, I think it makes more sense to fall back on the idea that ***English only has two tenses - Present and "Not-Present"***, since we're not really talking about "the past" (it's *not present because it's not real*, rather than *not present because it's long gone*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then I can think of having no problems in my sentence except adding "when "?

Comment: « As per the rule we should use "present tense" after time clause, including "when" » — Who in the world taught you this utterly nonsensical ‘rule’? The presence or absence of a temporal clause is utterly unrelated to what tense you use for the main verb in a sentence.

Comment: Unlike your first sentence, your second sentence is not hypothetical and so you are working from at least one false assumption. @JanusBahsJacquet mentions another. These make it difficult to answer your question at all. What is your first language? We need to understand where you are coming from here. Perhaps you would do better at our sister-site for [ell.se].

Comment: @dz420: I see no problem, no. But then again I see no problem with [*If that **happens** we would (do such-and-such)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if+that+happens+we+would%22). I'm quite well aware *some* people would carp at that and say it should be *If that **happened**...* (or *If that **were to happen**...,* for subjunctive diehards). But I'm not really into the kind of grammar rules that need to be actually *taught* - only the kind that all native speakers honour without thinking (because of how they've heard others speak over a lifetime).

Comment: @tchrist It seeems not be hypothetical now because you have edited my question wrongly. sorry. The first one was a question, like - What if I were a king?  And the second one was the answer, like- I would  buy a car. It should be hypothetical because I ain't a king and I won't buy a car.

Comment: @dz420 If our edits changed your question into something other than you intended, please edit it back into what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

"*As per the rule* we should use "present tense" after time clause, including "when". But since it's a hypothetical sentence I should use "past" tense here, shouldn't I? Is my sentence correct?"

It's not a matter of rules. It never is.

The problem is fictitious in this case for "when" is redundant here, unnecessarily put in, just to complicate things. You are already stating the time, which is the cut-off time. Never mind if you are speaking hypothetically. You say "I (would) smile to her every time we (met) meet", not "I smile to her every time WHEN we meet". Likewise, you say "… every time the electricity supply (was/is) cut off", not "every time WHEN the electricity supply (was/is) cut off". So, your sentence is neither correct nor incorrect, only unreal.

A different question would be, "When I (met) meet her, I (would) smile to her every time" (or, rather more awkwardly, "I (would) smile to her every time, when I (met) meet her"), meaning you can't refrain from it, that for whatever whatever the reason you never fail to do it. That's not the case in your example.

As I said, it's never a matter of rules. It's a matter of the function the rules serve. You need to grasp it to know how to use—or not to use—the rule, or to see why it's not relevant.